# Исходники с какой лицензией свободны для некоммерческого испольования?

Tags: лицензирование

Где в инете видел лицензию под которой исходники свободны для некоммереческого использования. Т.е. изменяй, модифицируй как хочешь, только не продавай. Что за лицензия такая, не подскажите?

Comment: @SweetHorror, а в чем глубокий смысл запрета продаж?

Comment: @avp, очевидно, автор не отказывается от продаж, а не хочет чтобы без его ведома код использовали в коммерческом продукте. В любом случае он имеет на это право.  
Я сомневаюсь, что существует лицензия, запрещающая продажу вообще в принципе.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, подойдут

- [Creative Commons Attribution NonCommercial (CC-NC)](https://tldrlegal.com/license/creative-commons-attribution-noncommercial-(cc-nc))
- [Creative Commons Attribution NonCommercial ShareAlike (CC-NC-SA)](https://tldrlegal.com/license/creative-commons-attribution-noncommercial-sharealike-(cc-nc-sa))